# Swift: error: use of instance member on type

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I'm trying to build a swift script but I got stuck with this error:

```
./1.swift:10:11: error: use of instance member 'thisIsmyFunction' on type 'myScript'; did you mean to use a value of type 'myScript' instead?
 myScript.thisIsmyFunction()
 ~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
import Foundation
class myScript {
    func thisIsmyFunction() {
        print("Do something in there!")
    }
}
myScript.thisIsmyFunction()
```

What I'm trying to do is access to the function and execute the print.

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: As an aside, but naming conventions suggest that you should start your class name with an uppercase letter. So you'd call it `MyScript`, not `myScript`. This makes it easier to differentiate between the class, and an instance of that class (e.g. `let script = MyScript(); script.thisIsmyFunction()`).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can only call an instance method on an instance of a class. For example, you would have to create an instance of `myScript`, then call it:

```
let script = myScript()
script.thisIsmyFunction()
```

You can also choose to make `thisIsmyFunction` a class method (which is formally known as a "type method" in Swift), and call it like the way you are doing right now:

```
class func thisIsmyFunction() {...}
```

Note the `class` modifier in front of `func`. Of course, this means you can't access `self` inside the function, because there is no longer an instance of the class.

For more information, see the [Swift documentation on methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html).

*Aside: Swift classes should start with capital letters.*

Comment: Great tip about the class modifier! Cleared things up a lot.